# C# - How to Transfer Information Between User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

im doing an application where user enter a value inside the text box then he press a button, both in the same user control. Then the result from the text box will show at the label of other user control. Both of the user control is in the same windows form.

Thanks!

[Image of user interface](http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/12049907/img/12049907.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Please provide some of your code so we can see what you have to start

Comment: And also - is this WPF or windows forms?

Comment: What UI design pattern are you using. Your controller should be able to trigger the label update by updating its dependency property.

Comment: soryy im new here... @theodox ...i use windows form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
public class FirstUserControl:UserControl
{
    Public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    //Public property in your first usercontrol
    public string MyText
    {
        get{return this.textbox1.Text;} //textbox1 is the name of your textbox
    }

    private void MyButton_Clicked(/* args */)
    {
        if (MyEvent!=null)
        {
            MyEvent(null, null);
        }
    }
    //other codes
}


public class SecondUserControl:UserControl
{
    //Public property in your first usercontrol
    public string MyText
    {
        set{this.label1.Text = value;} //label1 is the name of your label
    }

    //other codes
}
```

then in your MainForm:

```
public class MainForm:Forms
{
    //Add two instance of the UserControls

    public MainForm()
    {
        this.firstUserControl.MyEvent += MainWindow_myevent;
    }

    void MainWindow_myevent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.secondUserControl.MyText = this.firstUserControl.MyText;
    }

    //other codes
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most common way to do this is use an event. This is how I would do it:

First define an EventArgs:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Text { get; private set; }

    public MyEventArgs(string Text)
    {
        this.Text = Text;
    }
}
```

Then in your UserControl (the one with the button):

```
public partial class MyUserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> ButtonClicked;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        //...

        button1.Click += (o, e) => OnButtonClicked(new MyEventArgs(textBox1.Text));
    }

    protected virtual void OnButtonClicked(MyEventArgs args)
    {
        var hand = ButtonClicked;
        if(hand != null) ButtonClicked(this, args);
    }
}
```

Then subscribe to your `MyUserControl.ButtonClicked` event in the form and call a method in the second control.

---

Note if the behavior of the button and the text in the textbox are actually *not* related, you can use a property to get the text entered and an empty `EventArgs` for your event instead.

P.S. The names `MyEventArgs`, `MyUserControl`, and `ButtonClicked` are just for demonstration purposes. I encourage you to use more descriptive/relevant naming in your code.